# C# String replace XML Tags with other Tags

Tags: c#, html, xml, string

I am building a Chat parser that should replace XML tags (in a string) describing an emoticon with HTML image tags having a link to the related emoticon file.

Example Chat Text:

```
Hi there <ss type="tongueout">:p</ss><ss type="laugh">:D</ss>
```

Should be changed to the following:

```
Hi there <img src="./Emoticons/toungeout.png" /><img src="./Emoticons/laugh.png" />
```

The image files are all named like the corresponding "type"-attribute.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
var smilies = XElement.Parse(text)
                      .Descendants("ss")
                      .Select(x => x.Attribute("type").Value); 

Regex.Replace(text, "<.*?>", String.Empty); 
foreach (var smily in smilies) 
{ 
    text += "<img src=\"./Emoticons/" + smily + ".png\" />";
}
```

This added all smilies at the end of the text, but is not capable of putting them within the text.

Comment: I tried several String-, and Regex Replacement Functions

Comment: Then post what you have tried and the corresponding result

Comment: `var smilies = XElement.Parse(text)
                       .Descendants("ss")
                       .Select(x => x.Attribute("type").Value);
                Regex.Replace(text, "<.*?>", String.Empty);

                foreach (var smily in smilies)
                {
                    text += "<img src=\"./Emoticons/" + smily + ".png\" />";
                }`         

This added all smilies at the end of the text, but is not capable of putting them within the text.

Comment: Consider editing that into your answer. I myself cannot help you, but I'm sure someone else would after seeing you have put effort into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Globalization;


namespace ConsoleApplication53
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
              "<Root>" +
                  "<ss type=\"tongueout\">:p</ss><ss type=\"laugh\">:D</ss>" +
              "</Root>";

            XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);

            XElement[]  img = new XElement[] {
                   new XElement("img", new XAttribute("src","./Emoticons/toungeout.png")), 
                   new XElement("img", new XAttribute("src", "./Emoticons/laugh.png")) 
            };

            XElement ss = root.Element("ss");
            ss.ReplaceWith(img);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution:

```
string[] split = Regex.Split(text, "</ss>");

            text = "";

            foreach (string s in split)
            {
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\btype="")[^""]*");
                string smily = regex.Match(s).Value;

                string result = Regex.Replace(s, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
                writer.WriteEncodedText(result);

                if (smily != string.Empty)
                {
                    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, "./Emoticons/" + smily + ".png");
                    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Img);
                }
            }
```